# how to rewrite url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

https://example.in/mesurements/index/booking/ 
something like 
https://example.in/booking/
 Someone help Me

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can add the following lines to your .htaccess file in the document root folder:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^booking/(.*)$ /mesurements/index/booking/$1